# What do we call this adjustable platform used to ensure that something is positioned strictly level in a lab?

Tags: terminology, gel-electrophoresis, materials

[image]

This is an adjustable platform. Such a platform is used, for example, to make sure that a gel electrophoresis cassette is level relative to the earth. A passage in a procedure description which I'm translating says that the gel caster (the two glass plates between which we will pour the solution) should be put on top of this platform, after which the platform is adjusted "using a level". The text describes a vertical SDS-PAGE procedure.

I wonder what such benchtop lab platforms are called. In my Russian text it is called "заливочный столик" (pouring table, casting table).

Comment: I have never in my 5+ years in academic labs seen anyone use an adjustable platform for leveling... In general all tables in a lab should be level checked at installation so using such a platform would be overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember using those for agarose gels as an undergraduate, though using them for PAGE doesn't make a lot of sense unless your bench is seriously out of level. Anyways, they can be called [levelling tables](https://www.google.ca/search?sclient=tablet-gws&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=electrophoresis+levelling+table&oq=electrophoresis+levelling+table&gs_l=tablet-gws.3..35i39k1.1922.1922.0.2607.1.1.0.0.0.0.119.119.0j1.1.0....0...1.2.64.tablet-gws..0.1.119.tr_BwdVxn1k) and are used to promote uniform migration across the gel. Casting table also seems reasonable.